# Bootstrap 4 app and _settings like sass files not found

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

The Bootstrap 4 documentation does not mention how to effectively work with sass files.  Unlike Foundation it is clear that the app.scss is the final sass file that is executed and is where you you include partials, also the _settings.scss is where you make customization. Question is what are the similar files in Bootstrap 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_variables.scss` is the file containing settings

`bootstrap.scss` is the final file that includes the partials

Answer (score 0):

You can check Ohm - Omega 4 example theme, maybe you could find something helpful: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/omega/tree/ohm/sass